# Поворот коллайдера в CharacterConroller

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Когда я пытаюсь изменить поворот объекта, к которому прикреплен CharacterController, то коллайдер, который находится внутри этого компонента, не поворачивается вместе с этим объектом. Как сделать так, чтобы поворачивался?

Comment: Какого типа у вас колайдер? наедюсь box collider,  и ещё колайдер должен быть дочерним обиекту которого вы вращаете

Comment: Rigidbody vs capsule collider тебе в помощь